# Copy Blob Data To Sql Database in Azure Data Factory with Conditions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am performing a a trigger based pipeline to copy data from blob storage to SQL database. In every blob file there are bunch of JSONs from which I need to copy just few of them and I can differenciate them on the basis of a Key-value pair present in every JSON.

So How to filter those JSON containing that Value corresponding to a common key?

One Blob file looks like this. Now While the copy activity is happening ,it should filter data according to the Event- Name: "...".

[image: Inside BLOB File example (5 json present)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data factory in general only moves data, it doesnt modify it. What you are trying to do might be done using a staging table in the sink sql.

You should first load the json values as-is from the blob storage in the staging table, then copy it from the staging table to the real table where you need it, applying your logic to filter in the sql command used to extract it.

Remember that sql databases have built in functions to treat json values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks For your help.! I understand your point and maybe it could help me also. But the main point is instead of using staging table I can directly load everything in  a SQL table as well and then move it further with modifying it. Main point it anyhow I will be paying while the data is been written inside the staging table from blob storage, so i am paying for writing whole data. Instead I just want to copy certain selected data so that cost of copying would be reduced. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: As I said, data factory does not modify or filters data by its own. You can do this now with data flows, but that requires a databricks cluster and will be much more expensive than what I'm suggesting. If you find a cheaper way than what I said, please tell me! :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. So I went for the expensive way of data bricks but data flow does not support JSON (my data format). Now how to transform it? using python? if yes then can you please guide me the process a bit?

Answer (score -1):

At this time we do not have an option for the copy activity to filter the content( with an exception of sql source )  . 
In your scenario it looks like that already know which values needs to omitted , on way to go will be have a "Stored Procedure" activity , after the copy activity which will be just delete the values which you don't want from the table ,this should be easy to implement but depending on the volume of data it may lead to performance issues . The other option is to have the JSON file cleaned on the storage side before it is ingested .

Comment: Thanks for your help !. You are right. SO the case is that we are exporting data from APP Center to Application insights and then a continuous export to a storage account. Do you know is there a way out in this cycle to filter out the data. Or do you have any other idea to use maybe different storage for application insight export so that we can have a control over data modification.